# bootstrap navbar dropdown list

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Dropdown link
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

this is the code for navbar with dropdowns in bootstrap. but the problem is here dropdown is not working when is a toggle to the navbar dropdown icon

code Link: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/
any suggestions why it isn't working for react??

Comment: Did you include jquery and bootstrap.js in your html file?

Comment: You should use react bootstrap components for this - https://react-bootstrap.github.io/
But I think you are not loading all the required jquery and css and bootstrap scripts

Answer (score 0):

You need to use reactstrap npm package together with bootstrap. have a look here: https://reactstrap.github.io/

Answer (score 0):

You should use react-bootstrap. It works fine with react and is specially made for react.
https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/navbar/#navbars-overview